# Calling 2 functions from within a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

I am a relative newbie and am trying to help myself understand functions better. I have created an exercise for myself

Write a simple program to:

1. Ask 3 simple Qs
2. Respond to each Q depending on what user inputs (each Q response is determined by one of 3 unique functions)
3. Put those answers into a simple summary sentence at the end

I'm using one function as the main 'controller' --> **questions()**

I want to call **questions()** and then from within - call the other 3 functions. I have a feeling my functions need arguments - but I'm not sure how (I have tried putting arguments in the various functions - but have got completely stuck - returning errors (please see below))

My code:

```
def naming(): # function to respond to name as per user input 
    if in_name == 'David':
        print 'That\'s a cool name!!'
    elif in_name == 'Jane':
        print 'That\'s a great name!!'
    else:
        print 'That\'s an OK name!!!'

def age(): # function to respond to age as per user input 
    if in_age > 60:
        print 'That\'s old!!'
    elif in_age < 15:
        print 'That\'s young!!'
    else:
        print 'That\'s neither young nor old!!'

def loc(): # function to respond to location as per user input 
    if in_loc == 'London':
        print 'London is a big city!!'
    elif in_loc == 'Manchester':
        print 'Manchester is a wonderful place!!'
    else:
        print 'That sounds OK!!'


def questions(): #function to own the whole process (name + age + loc)
    in_name = raw_input('What is your name? -->')
    naming()
    in_age = input('How old are you? -->')
    age()
    in_loc = raw_input('Where do you live? -->')
    loc()
    print 'Your name is',in_name,', you are' ,in_age , 'years old and you live in' , in_loc,'.'

questions()
```

I'm guessing that within the main **questions()** function - I need to provide some form of instruction or argument within the **naming/age/loc** functions

Would really appreciate some help here! Yes - there are a few other similar threads on here - but I have read them and none make sense to me. 
Ideally - the most helpful thing for me would be if some good samaritan could spend 3 or 4 minutes to edit my code to operate correctly.

Thanks in advance!

PS - here's the screenshot of the error I'm getting
[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable which is defined inside a function is local to that function. It is accessible from the point at which it is defined until the end of the function and exists for as long as the function is executing.

1. you can pass the values as arguments to other functions

   ```
   def naming(in_name): # function to respond to name as per user input 
       if in_name == 'David':
           print 'That\'s a cool name!!'
       elif in_name == 'Jane':
           print 'That\'s a great name!!'
       else:
           print 'That\'s an OK name!!!'

   def age(in_age): # function to respond to age as per user input 
       if in_age > 60:
           print 'That\'s old!!'
       elif in_age < 15:
           print 'That\'s young!!'
       else:
           print 'That\'s neither young nor old!!'

   def loc(in_loc): # function to respond to location as per user input 
       if in_loc == 'London':
           print 'London is a big city!!'
       elif in_loc == 'Manchester':
           print 'Manchester is a wonderful place!!'
       else:
           print 'That sounds OK!!'


   def questions(): #function to own the whole process (name + age + loc)
       in_name = raw_input('What is your name? -->')
       naming(in_name)
       in_age = input('How old are you? -->')
       age(in_age)
       in_loc = raw_input('Where do you live? -->')
       loc(in_loc)
       print 'Your name is',in_name,', you are' ,in_age , 'years old and you live in' , in_loc,'.'

   questions()
   ```
2. otherwise you can define the variables as **global**, so you don't have to pass it as an argument.(This method is not recommended)

   ```
   def naming(): # function to respond to name as per user input 
       if in_name == 'David':
           print 'That\'s a cool name!!'
       elif in_name == 'Jane':
           print 'That\'s a great name!!'
       else:
           print 'That\'s an OK name!!!'

   def age(): # function to respond to age as per user input 
       if in_age > 60:
           print 'That\'s old!!'
       elif in_age < 15:
           print 'That\'s young!!'
       else:
           print 'That\'s neither young nor old!!'

   def loc(): # function to respond to location as per user input 
       if in_loc == 'London':
           print 'London is a big city!!'
       elif in_loc == 'Manchester':
           print 'Manchester is a wonderful place!!'
       else:
           print 'That sounds OK!!'


   def questions(): #function to own the whole process (name + age + loc)
       global in_name, in_age, in_loc
       in_name = raw_input('What is your name? -->')
       naming()
       in_age = input('How old are you? -->')
       age()
       in_loc = raw_input('Where do you live? -->')
       loc()
       print 'Your name is',in_name,', you are' ,in_age , 'years old and you live in' , in_loc,'.'

   questions()
   ```

Comment: Brilliant! Many thanks for this. A really helpful answer - I was almost there myself - but couldn;t get any further. So thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Variable in the function `questions()` is not known to the other functions(or their scope is restricted to `questions()` function ) , That's why you are getting error, not defined

```
def naming(in_name): # function to respond to name as per user input 
    if in_name == 'David':
        print 'That\'s a cool name!!'
    elif in_name == 'Jane':
        print 'That\'s a great name!!'
    else:
        print 'That\'s an OK name!!!'

def age(in_age): # function to respond to age as per user input 
    if in_age > 60:
        print 'That\'s old!!'
    elif in_age < 15:
        print 'That\'s young!!'
    else:
        print 'That\'s neither young nor old!!'

def loc(in_loc): # function to respond to location as per user input 
    if in_loc == 'London':
        print 'London is a big city!!'
    elif in_loc == 'Manchester':
        print 'Manchester is a wonderful place!!'
    else:
        print 'That sounds OK!!'


def questions(): #function to own the whole process (name + age + loc)
    in_name = raw_input('What is your name? -->')
    naming(in_name)
    in_age = input('How old are you? -->')
    age(in_age)
    in_loc = raw_input('Where do you live? -->')
    loc(in_loc)
    print 'Your name is',in_name,', you are' ,in_age , 'years old and you live in' , in_loc,'.'

questions()
```

Comment: Many thanks for this - it all makes sense to me now. Very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to pass them as arguments to the functions.

```
def naming(in_name): # function to respond to name as per user input 
    if in_name == 'David':
        print 'That\'s a cool name!!'
    elif in_name == 'Jane':
        print 'That\'s a great name!!'
    else:
        print 'That\'s an OK name!!!'

def questions(): #function to own the whole process (name + age + loc)
    in_name = raw_input('What is your name? -->')
    naming(in_name)
```

Again variable `in_age`, it need to convert to `int` as `raw_input` is by default in `string` format.

```
in_age = input('How old are you? -->')
age(int(in_age))
```

Comment: I downwoted because the advice regarding global definition is a bad one, imo. It solves the `NameError`, but doesn't really solve the problem (passing a variable as an arugment to a function) and in general using such global scopes should be avoided (if variable is not some configuration constant).

Comment: @Robin. Yes..its True. I haven't tested code before. Removed that part.